# how to post array of images in multipart http post request

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I want to upload array of images, how should I append `array` to `NSMutableData`. here is my code

```
func createBodyWithParametersMulti(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: [NSData?], boundary: String) -> NSData {
        let body = NSMutableData();

        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {
                body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
            }
        }

        if(imageDataKey.count != 0){
            let filename=filePathKey as! String
            // let mimetype = "image/jpeg"

            body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filename)\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n")
            // body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n")
            body.appendString("Content-Type: \("image.jpeg")\r\n\r\n")


            body.append(imageDataKey[0]! as Data)
               body.appendString("\r\n")
           }
        else {

        }
        body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")

        return body
    }
```

`ImageDataKey` is the name of the `array` containing multiple images as a `NSData`.

Comment: Use for loop and append one by one image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**

```
func createBodyWithParametersAndImages(parameters: [String: Any]?, filePathKey: [String], imageDataKey: [Data], boundary: String) -> NSData {
    let body = NSMutableData();

    if parameters != nil {
        for (key, value) in parameters! {
            body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }

    for index in 0..<imageDataKey.count {
        let data = imageDataKey[index]

        let filename = "image.jpeg"
        let mimetype = "image/jpeg"

        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey[index])\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.append(data)
        body.appendString(string: "\r\n")

    }


    body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")

    return body
}
```

**Method Calling**

```
let body = createBodyWithParametersAndImages(parameters: parameter, filePathKey: ["profile_image", "cover_image"], imageDataKey: [imageData1, ImageData2] as! [NSData], boundary: boundary) as Data
request.httpBody = body
```

Comment: success should be shown like this  "Image": [
            "1523612490901-photo-1507804032213",
            "1523612490903-photo-1507803950846"
        ],

Comment: @Abathla didn't understand. can you please explain?

Comment: this function we usually run when we have to send multiple images but parameters of all of them is different say image,image1... and so on.but I am having an array of imageData that I want to post in a single parameter named "image" and after success images should be shown on the server in a array like this                                      "Image": [ "1523612490901-photo-1507804032213", "1523612490903-photo-1507803950846" ]

Comment: @Abathla Try to set filePathKey: ["image", "image"]. Pass same key in array.

Comment: @Abathla Welcome ✌️